# Finding a basis of $Ker(T)$ and rank–nullity theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

$T(x,y,z) = (x+y, x+z,y+z)$.

Finding a basis of $ker(T)$.

Find the null space of:

$ \displaylines{\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\ 1&0&1 \\ 0&1&1 \end{bmatrix}.
\\rref =\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\ 0&1&0 \\ 0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}.
\\
}$

Therefore there is no basis, since this system has a unique solution. Does this mean that the dimension of $Im(T) = 3$? By rank–nullity theorem

Comment: The image of your matrix is $\mathbb R^3,$ so yes it has dimension $3,$ and this is also true by virtue of the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: @StephenDonovan Thank you!

Comment: @StephenDonovan T is surjective, correct?

Comment: @Mark12 it is surjective

Comment: @Mark12 Thank you. I was a little confused if it is surjective, as in my reasoning it could only be surjective if it had at least one basis for Ker (T). To have a connection between the domain and the codomain.